# Get all videos of a YouTube Playlist in Java

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, playlist, youtube-data-api

**Context** I'm working with Android Studio (Java). I want to obtain all the videos of a given playlist (or 50, I will get all the other after).

**Problem** I see people using url like 
`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=PLiEwZfNgb4fVrRzTonlVEMj6DB2Nmzg2M&key=AIzaSyC2_YRcTE9916fsmA0_KRnef43GbLzz8m0`
 but I don't know how to implement this in Java. I follow some tuto and I got a way to get information totally different like :

```
YouTube.Search.List query;
query = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");
      query.setKey(MY_API_KEY);
      query.setMaxResults((long)20);
      query.setType("video");
      query.setFields("items(id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/description,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
```

And I really don't understand how do I get something else than a search.
Most of documentation is in english only...

**EDIT**
Ok, so I continued to try, I think I got a near solution, but I got an error.

```
private YouTube youtube;
private YouTube.PlaylistItems.List playlistItemRequest;
private String PLAYLIST_ID = "PLiEwZfNgb4fVrRzTonlVEMj6DB2Nmzg2M";
public static final String KEY = "AIzaSyC2_YRcTE9916fsmA0_KRnef43GbLzz8m0";

// Constructor
public YoutubeConnector(Context context)
{
    youtube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
            new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer()
    {
        @Override
        public void initialize(HttpRequest hr) throws IOException {}
    }).setApplicationName(context.getString(R.string.app_name)).build();
}

public List<VideoItem> result()
{
    List<PlaylistItem> playlistItemList = new ArrayList<PlaylistItem>();
    try
    {
    /* HERE MUST BE MY PROBLEM ! */
        playlistItemRequest = youtube.playlistItems().list("snippet");
        playlistItemRequest.setPlaylistId(PLAYLIST_ID);
        playlistItemRequest.setFields("items(id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/description,snippet/thumbnails/default/url),nextPageToken,pageInfo");
        playlistItemRequest.setKey(KEY);
        String nextToken = "";
        do {
            playlistItemRequest.setPageToken(nextToken);
            PlaylistItemListResponse playlistItemResult = playlistItemRequest.execute();

            playlistItemList.addAll(playlistItemResult.getItems());

            nextToken = playlistItemResult.getNextPageToken();
        } while (nextToken != null);
    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        Log.d("YC", "Could not initialize: "+e);
    }
//[...]
}
```

Here is the error I got :

`{
"code" : 400, 
    "errors" : [ {
        "domain" : "global", 
        "location" : "fields", 
        "locationType" : "parameter", 
        "message" : "Invalid field selection videoId", 
        "reason" : "invalidParameter"
     } ],
     "message" : "Invalid field selection videoId"
}`

**EDIT 2** Thanks to : Martijn Woudstra.
Correct line was :

```
playlistItemRequest = youtube.playlistItems().list("snippet,contentDetails");
//[...]
playlistItemRequest.setFields("items(snippet/title,snippet/description,snippet/thumbnails/default/url,contentDetails/videoId),nextPageToken,pageInfo");
//[...]
videoItem.setId(item.getContentDetails().getVideoId());
```

Comment: I added an answer to your question ~ hope you find it useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that is an old question but It is important to identify which resources are we using to understand how to get the proper information. There are many resources in the YouTube API v3, but we usually use the `search`, `video`, `playlist` and `playlistItems`.

According to the documentation the following JSON structure shows the format of a `playlistItems` resource:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": datetime,
    "channelId": string,
    "title": string,
    "description": string,
    "thumbnails": {
      (key): {
        "url": string,
        "width": unsigned integer,
        "height": unsigned integer
      }
    },
    "channelTitle": string,
    "playlistId": string,
    "position": unsigned integer,
    "resourceId": {
      "kind": string,
      "videoId": string,
    }
  },
  "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": string,
    "startAt": string,
    "endAt": string,
    "note": string,
    "videoPublishedAt": datetime
  },
  "status": {
    "privacyStatus": string
  }
}
```

From this structure, we may suppose that there are three ways to get the `videoId`. But first it is important to know how we going to define the *PARTS* and the *FIELDS* of the resource.

To define the *PARTS* we use this code:

```
YouTube.PlaylistItems.List list = youtube.playlistItems().list("snippet");
```

In the previous line, `"snippet"` identifies a property that contains numerous fields (or child properties), including the `title`, `description`, `position`, and `resourceId`, so when we set `"snippet"` the API's response will contain all of those child properties.

Now, we also can limit the previous properties if we define the FIELDS. For example, in this code:

```
list.setFields("items(id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/description," +
    "snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
```

If we call `list.execute()`, it will show an error because we didn't define `id` in the *PARTS* properties. Also, according to the *JSON* structure, `id` is a String and does not contains `videoId` as a child property. Ah!, but we can extract `videoId` from the `resourceId`? -Well, the answers is **YES/NO**. -Why so? Come on Teo, the *JSON* structure shows it clearly. -Yes, I can see that, but the documentation says:

> If the `snippet.resourceId.kind` property's value is `youtube#video`, then this property will be present and its value will contain the ID that YouTube uses to uniquely identify the video in the playlist.

This means that **sometimes** may not be available. -Then, how we can get the `videoId`? -Well, we can add `id` or `contentDetails` to the PARTS resources. If we add `id` then defines fields like this:

```
YouTube.PlaylistItems.List list = youtube.playlistItems().list("id,snippet");
list.setFields("items(id,snippet/title,snippet/description," +
    "snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
```

If we add `contentDetails` then defines fields like this:

```
YouTube.PlaylistItems.List list = youtube.playlistItems()
    .list("snippet,contentDetails");
list.setFields("items(contentDetails/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/description," +
    "snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
```

I hope this helps you guys.

Answer (score 2):

`id/videoId` doesnt exist.
There is an `id` and a `snippet/resourceId/videoId`.
So my guess is your setfields aren't right.

Comment: I don't know why it's not the same hierarchy in the website and in the code, but I was item/ContentDetails/VideoId.
Your comment help me a lot, thanks.